# header files not found even though they should be installed

Tags: ros, catkin-make, cmake, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a package A which only contains a header file to use in some other packages. But when trying to use the header in project B I always get the error "File not found". I found some questions here addressing the problem as "install issue". But I have the installation in my CMakeLists.txt of package A.

I also included ${CATKIN_INCLUDE_DIRS} in project B, but it still does not find the header file.

CMakeLists.txt of A:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(A)
## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  ndt_map
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  include
)

#############
## Install ##
#############

## Mark cpp header files for installation
 install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
 )
```

important part of CMakeLists.txt of project B:

```
find_package( catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
   A
)
include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188729/header-files-not-found-even-though-they-should-be-installed/) by [HyEnd](https://answers.ros.org/users/18036/hyend/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to installing header files, you also need to use the catkin_package command to inform other packages about where to find your header files when building from source in the same workspace:

```
catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-04**:
In addition to this: OP used `find_package(A)`, but there is no corresponding `include_directories([..] ${A_INCLUDE_DIRS} [..])`. Only `find_package()` is not enough. Alternatively, list `A` in `find_package(catkin COMPONENTS [..] A [..])`. Only then you rely on `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS`.

**Comment by [HyEnd](https://answers.ros.org/users/18036/hyend/) on 2014-08-04**:
thank you both for your answers, @ahendrix approach was enough to solve the problem.

@gvdhoom I actually used the "catkin COMPONENTS" tag, but I'm afraid I forgot to mention that in my question...

**Comment by [Combinacijus](https://answers.ros.org/users/44007/combinacijus/) on 2021-08-08**:
Had problem that no headers were found. Adding `include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})` fixed it thanks